# Asynchronous TCP server code example analysis

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, tcp, asyncsocket

I'm using the following code to create an asynchronous TCP server:

```
private void SetupServerSocket()
{
    var myEndpoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, _port);

    _serverSocket = new Socket(myEndpoint.Address.AddressFamily, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
    _serverSocket.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.KeepAlive, true);
    _serverSocket.Bind(myEndpoint);
    _serverSocket.Listen((int)SocketOptionName.MaxConnections);
}

protected void Open()
{
    SetupServerSocket();
    Opened = true;
    _serverSocket.BeginAccept(AcceptCallback, _serverSocket);
}

private void AcceptCallback(IAsyncResult result)
{
    var connection = new ConnectionInfo();
    try
    {
        // Finish Accept
        var s = (Socket)result.AsyncState;
        connection.Socket = s.EndAccept(result);
        connection.Buffer = new byte[8192];

        lock (_connections)
        {
            _connections.Add(connection);
        }

        // Start Receive and a new Accept
        connection.Socket.BeginReceive(connection.Buffer, 0, connection.Buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, ReceiveCallback, connection); 
        _serverSocket.BeginAccept(AcceptCallback, result.AsyncState);
    }
    catch (SocketException ex)
    {
        CloseConnection(connection);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        CloseConnection(connection);
    }
}

private void CloseConnection(ConnectionInfo ci)
    {
        if (ci.Socket != null)
        {
            if (OnDisconnect != null)
                OnDisconnect.Invoke((IPEndPoint)ci.Socket.RemoteEndPoint);

            ci.Socket.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
            ci.Socket.Close();
        }

        lock (_connections)
        {
            _connections.Remove(ci);
        }
    }
```

There are some things that are hard to understand:

1 - Using `_serverSocket.SetSocketOption` I enabled the use of KeepAlive in TCP. I discovered that Windows by default has the default KeepAlive Timer of 2 hours! and this behavior was confirmed using Wireshark.

After some Googling I found in http://support.microsoft.com/kb/120642/EN-US that you can change Windows KeepAliveTime by creating a key in registry. I did like this support page instructs but the KeepAlive Timer was not applied (even after rebooting), it's still 2 hours. Does anyone know how to change KeepAlive Timer in Windows?

2 - The code `connection.Socket = s.EndAccept(result)` can thrown exceptions (usually SocketException). Why `Socket.EndResult` throws `SocketException`?

3 - Why do we have to set `_serverSocket` in Accept state again in `AcceptCallback()` if it was already in that state?

Answer (score 1):

1. I had similar problems with the .net Keep Alive timer. I never found a way to change it so the solution we used was to have a background worker thread that sends a small amount of data, generally `byte[1]`, after a given time period if other real data had not been sent.
2. Socket.EndAccept() can throw the expected exceptions as per the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/chfa7866.aspx). These generally occur if something has happened to the socket elsewhere, such as the socket being closed etc. You need to correctly catch these exceptions and decide how you want your program to continue. In your case it looks like you are just closing the connection.
3. Calling `_serverSocket.BeginAccept(AcceptCallback, result.AsyncState);` will trigger the callback only ONCE for whichever connection is accepted first. After this you have to decide whether you want to accept further future connections, if so by calling BeginAccept again within the callback.

Comment: Where in MSDN documentation says that BeginAccept will trigger the callback only once?

Comment: "This method is called once for each asynchronous request" - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.asynccallback.aspx

Comment: Can I set _serverSocket.BeginAccept(AcceptCallback, result.AsyncState) in the first line of AcceptCallback method to garantee that server socket will return to Accept state?

Comment: You can call BeginAccept as soon as EndAccept has returned successfully. If you do it the other way round your going to run into problems.